# Prove that $A = aI+B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

Let $A \in M_{n\times n}(F)$.
Show that $A = aI+B$, where $a \in F, B \in M_{n\times n}(F)$ and $\operatorname{tr}(B) = 0$.

I just need a hint to start proving this.

**Solved**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\operatorname{char} F$ does not divide $n$, then you can let $a = \text{average of the diagonal elements of } A.$

In other words:
$$a = \dfrac{1}{n}\operatorname{tr} A.$$

Then, let $B = A - aI$. Clearly, you have $A = aI + B$. Moreover,
$$\operatorname{tr}B = \operatorname{tr}(A - aI) = \operatorname{tr}(A) - a\operatorname{tr}(I) = \operatorname{tr}A - na = \operatorname{tr}A - \operatorname{tr}A = 0.$$

---

On the other hand, if $\operatorname{char} F$ does divide $n$, then you cannot find such $a, B$ in general. For example, let $F = \Bbb F_2$ and consider
$$A = \begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Suppose that we did have $A = aI + B$ with $\operatorname{tr}B= 0$.
Note that $\operatorname{tr}I = \operatorname{tr}B = 0$ and thus, we'd get that $\operatorname{tr}A = 0$, a contradiction.

In such a case, we can find an $a$ and $B$ if and only if $\operatorname{tr}A = 0$.
The "only if" follows from an argument as the one given above.
The "if" part follows by letting $A = B$ and $a = 0.$

Comment: Thank you, but can you give a hint of how to use the trace definition *only* to prove this? It would be nicer :)

Comment: Using the trace definition, you should be able to prove the following for matrices: $\operatorname{tr}(aA + B) = a\operatorname{tr}A + \operatorname{tr}B$ and $\operatorname{tr} I_n = n$. I think that is all that you need.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  $Tr(A-aI)$ equals $ Tr(A)-na$.

Comment: Yes, that totally works! Thank you. But I was looking for a way to prove this by using trace definition only.